# What are spark and spice architecture

Tags: architecture

What are spark and spice architecture in terms of IP comunication, Please explain.
Any pointers to documents for further reading will be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you Google for those terms first, read all you can about them, then come back to us with more specific questions.

Comment: @ChristianHayter I googled those terms and this StackOverflow question was the first hit...

Comment: When I search for "spice architecture" I get 5 useful matches *before* this question. Maybe we are falling foul of Google's per-user filtering of search results. :-(

Comment: I am a beginer with very basic knowledge of VOIP communication.My intent of posting this question is to get the advice of experts who has hands on experince on such architecture.Although there are some documents available over internet(for spice) which i found hard to understand :) at my first trial(so i posted this question). But anyways i will try to figure it out.

Comment: @Ashu: We are happy to give advice here, but you have to ask a specific question first, which does mean that you need a *basic* understanding of the subject before you start. The answer to a question like "tell me about X" will generally be "google for X".